# Round# counter won't reset when restarting the game & when user input is invalid

Tags: python

so i don't understand why my counter doesn't reset when i'm restarting the game, also, i believe its got something to do with the fact that i have no builder?
any help will be highly appriciated!

```
import random
import sys
from termcolor import colored

class RPS():

    def show_welcome():
        print(colored("Welcome to RPS !!!", 'blue'))
        print(colored("RULES:",'yellow'), colored("*", 'red'), "Rock Beats Scissors",colored("*", 'red'))
        print(colored("       *", 'grey'),"Scissors beats Paper", colored("*", 'grey'))
        print(colored("       *", 'magenta'), "Paper beats Rock", colored("*", 'magenta'))
        print(colored("!---=== GOOD LUCK ===---! ", 'green'))

    def round_number():
        x = 10
        user_input = ""

        while True:
            try:
                user_input = int(input("# Number Of Rounds? [Max 10]: "))
            except:
                print("Invalid Input!")
                RPS.round_number()

            if user_input < 1 or user_input > x:
                print("Max 10 rounds!")
                rundnum = 0
                RPS.round_number()
            else:
                return user_input

    def restart():
        user_input = ""
        try:
            user_input = input("Would you like to restart? [Y/n]")
        except:
            print("\nInvalid Input! ")
            RPS.show_welcome()

        if user_input is "y" or user_input is "Y":
            rounds = 0
            RPS.round_number()
        elif user_input is "n" or user_input is "N":
            print(colored("Thanks for playing! Goodbye!", 'green'))
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print("Bullshit input!")
            RPS.restart()

    def game():

        player = 0
        rounds = 0
        moves = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors',]
        r = rundnum

        while rounds < r:
            rounds += 1
            comp = random.choice(moves)

            print(colored("Choose : ", 'green'), colored("1)Rock", 'red'), colored("2)Paper", 'yellow'),
                  colored("3)Scissors", 'grey'))

            try:
                player = int(input("What's Your Guess? "))
            except:
                print(colored("No Valid Input! Restarting Game...", 'red'))
                RPS.game()

            if (player is 1 and comp is 'Rock') or (player is 2 and comp is 'Paper') \
                or (player is 3 and comp is 'Scissors'):

                print("Player Choose: {}".format(moves[player - 1]))
                print("Computer Choose: {}".format(comp))
                print(colored("*** Round #: {} | Result: It's A Draw !! *** ", 'blue').format(rounds))

                if rounds >= r:
                    print(colored("*** GAME OVER *** ", 'grey'))
                    rounds = 0
                    RPS.restart()
                else:
                    continue

            elif (player is 1 and comp is 'Paper') or (player is 2 and comp is 'Scissors') \
                or (player is 3 and comp is 'Rock'):

                print("Player Choose: {}".format(moves[player - 1]))
                print("Computer Choose: {}".format(comp))
                print(colored("*** Round #: {} | Result: Player Lose !! *** ", 'blue').format(rounds))

                if rounds >= r:
                    print(colored("*** GAME OVER *** ", 'grey'))
                    rounds = 0
                    RPS.restart()
                else:
                    continue

            elif (player is 1 and comp is 'Scissors') or (player is 2 and comp is 'Rock') \
                or (player is 3 and comp is 'Paper'):

                print("Player Choose: {}".format(moves[player - 1]))
                print("Computer Choose: {}".format(comp))
                print(colored("*** Round #: {} | Result: Player Wins !! *** ", 'blue').format(rounds))

                if rounds >= r:
                    print(colored("*** GAME OVER *** ", 'grey'))
                    rounds = 0
                    RPS.restart()
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                print(colored("No valid input!", 'red'))
                RPS.game()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #rounds = ""
    while True:
        RPS.show_welcome()
        rundnum = RPS.round_number()
        RPS.game()
        rounds = 0
        rundnum = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when you call `RPS.game()` within the function itself. This creates a situation whereby all the variables reset, as defined by the function `.game()`. To avoid this, you could give the function default parameters and then call the function (within itself) with those parameters.

Example (using part of the original code):

```
def game(player=0, rounds=0):

    # player = 0
    # rounds = 0
    moves = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors',]
    r = rundnum

    while rounds < r:
        rounds += 1
        comp = random.choice(moves)

        print(colored("Choose : ", 'green'), colored("1)Rock", 'red'), colored("2)Paper", 'yellow'),
              colored("3)Scissors", 'grey'))

        try:
            player = int(input("What's Your Guess? "))
        except:
            print(colored("No Valid Input! Restarting Game...", 'red'))
            RPS.game(player, rounds) # Here's the magic...
```